# Access a file upload without saving the file, and then emailing it as an attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am attempting to make a form that will send an email with an attachment using Action Mailer. I am not using a model to back the object that I am uploading. I would like to attach the file directly to the message without having to save it to the server hard drive. In my controller:

```
def create
    attachment = params[:attachment].read
    ApplicationRequestMailer.send_application_to_be_entered(current_user.member, attachment).deliver
    render :nothing => true
end
```

In my mailer:

```
class ApplicationRequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    def send_application_to_be_entered(member, file)
        attachment[file.origional_name] = file.read
        mail(:to => 'test@test.com', :subject => "To Be Entered")
    end

end
```

Is there any way to do this? or do I need to save the file out first using something like paperclip?

Comment: did you try that approach? i think that it should work, besides that you are reading the data two times...

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is completely correct, but it's working:

```
def create
    ApplicationRequestMailer.send_application_to_be_entered(params[:application].read(), params[:application].original_filename).deliver
    redirect_to dashboards_path, :notice => "Request Sent."  
end


def send_application_to_be_entered(file, filename)
    attachments[filename] = file
    mail(:to => 'test@test.com', :subject => "Application To Be Entered")
end
```